# how to add parameters Func<>

Tags: c#, reflection, func

I am trying to create a class that represents a function how can such a thing be achieved ??

i try to use this

```
public class Function : Value
{
    Func<Value, Value> Fun;

    public Function(Func<Value, Value> fun)
    {
        Fun = fun;
    }

    public override Value Execute(IEnumerable<Value> args)
    {
        if(args.Count() == 1)
            Fun(args.First());
        return Number.Empty;
    }
}
```

but i realy need in the constructor some think like this

```
Func<...Args> Fun;

public Function(Func<...Args> fun)
{
    Fun = fun;
}
```

Comment: `Func<IEnumerable<Value>, Value> Fun`?

Comment: That's not supported in C#. See duplicate. Your alternatives are to create multiple constructor overloads, one for each parameter count you want to support (similar to how `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` work) or to have a single parameter that is some kind of enumeration or collection, e.g. `Value[]`, similar to how C# handles methods with variable numbers of parameters.

Comment: Either use a `Delegate` variable, perhaps with N static factory methods, with a private constructor. Or define 1..N classes to mirror the c# definitions of `Func<...>` with 1..N generic parameters.